# Node js server. httpstatus - 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, http-status-code-404

I made a small server. When I am trying to make a get request to my server in browser i can see correct data, but when I am trying to make a post request to my server by code I get  httpstatus - 404. Why can it happened?

My server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.get('/api/check', function(req, res) {
    res.send('{"debug": "on"}');
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accepting POST requests to your API right now, only GET. To accept POST requests, add this:

```
app.post("/api/example", function(req, res) {
    // do your logic here
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Remember to read through the references. You’ll learn lots!

Answer (score 0):

Because your server doesn't have a **POST** route request handler. So it shows **404** Not Found Message. Add a POST route same as **GET**